# dask-worker memory kept between tasks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed

### Intro

I am parallelising some code using `dask.distributed` (embarrassingly parallel task).

- I have a list of Paths pointing to different images that I scatter to workers.
- Each worker loads and filters an image (3D stack) and run some filtering. 3D filtering with scipy saves intermediates outputs.
- Each filtered image is saved as npy and/or png on disk.
- I am testing locally before running on a cluster and my setup is:

.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=1,memory_limit =8e9)
client = Client(cluster)
```

### Issue:

- When I process only two images (1 image/worker) everything is fine
- When I scatter more than one image per worker I get this warnings in which the process memory value increases.

.

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.
Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 6.21 GB -- Worker memory limit: 8.00 GB
```

suggesting that part of the RAM used by the worker is non `freed` between the different files (I guess are leftover filtering intermediates....)

### Question

Is there a way to free the memory of the worker before starting the processing of the next image? do I have to run a `garbage collector` cycle in between running tasks?

#### edit

I included `gc.collect()` call at the end of the function run by the worker but didn't eliminate the warnings.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: did you get around this problem?

Comment: no, still an issue

Comment: I guess there is still no solution?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the reference count for a distributed value is held by a client the cluster won't purge it from memory. This is expounded on in the [Managing Memory](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/memory.html#clearing-data) documentation, specifically the "Clearing data" section.

Answer (score 1):

The "Memory use is high" error message could be pointing to a few potential culprits. I found [this article](https://coiled.io/blog/tackling-unmanaged-memory-with-dask/) by one of the core Dask maintainers helpful in diagnosing and fixing the issue.

Quick summary, either:

1. Break your data into smaller chunks.
2. Manually trigger garbage collection and/or tweak the gc settings on the workers through a Worker Plugin (which op has tried but doesn't work; I'll include anyway for other readers)
3. Trim memory using `malloc_trim` (esp. if working with non-NumPy data or small NumPy chunks)

Make sure you can see the Dask Dashboard while your computations are running to figure out which approach is working.